# I built my app Ionic App in Creator , now what?

Tags: ionic-framework

Im a total newbie, i finished my app and I want to put it up into the app stores but im lost in the middle step: here is my 2 min video question: http://somup.com/cFe6czVA96

Comment: Good job creating a video explaining the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Very well congratulations on building your first app and I really liked the way you made the video. There are few options if you could refer to this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) and this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) which will guide your through building the android and ios apps and pushing them to app store and or google play store. But you could also do the android builds locally and build the apk and deploy it to your mobile for further testing. Below are the items you would need. Happy coding

```
1. Android SDK (open source) / XCode (licenced)
2. Cordova - npm install -g cordova
3. Android emulatore or my favorite enable developer options on your android, if you have iOS you would need XCode
4. ionic cordova run ios / ionic cordova run android
5. See below examples

$ ionic cordova build ios
    $ ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
    $ ionic cordova build ios --device --prod --release -- --developmentTeam="ABCD" --codeSignIdentity="iPhone Developer" --packageType="app-store"
    $ ionic cordova build android
    $ ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --keystore=filename.keystore --alias=myalias
    $ ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --minSdkVersion=21
    $ ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --versionCode=55
    $ ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --gradleArg=-PcdvBuildMultipleApks=true
```